# Need encrypted virtual filesystem tool

Tags: encryption, virtualfilesystem

I am currently working on a project where i need to store few files and folders in encrypted manner. This project will be platform independent and hence will be written in Java.

Instead of encrypting individual file and folder, we have been thinking of using some virtual file-system where a single container file will hold complete file-system.

Most of the open source virtual encrypted file-system tools we studied work on following principle.

- mount the virtual file system (using secure password)
- use this filesystem
- finally dismount it

But the main problem here we face is that anyone who has access of the PC (e.g. network admin) will be able to see decrypted files when virtual drive is mounted. We want to restrict access to encrypted file system at **process level.** No one else in same OS session should be able to see the contents, hence no drive mounting, etc.

So we are looking for some open source tool which will provided some some APIs using which we will be able to access files in encrypted container without mounting it.

can anyone point us to any such library?

Comment: Instead, will it be a good idea to store files in MySQL/PGSQL database (in encrypted format)? This way platform dependency will not be an issue at all. Only thing is that i will need to think carefully about performance when it comes to storing HUGE files in database.

Comment: The open-source requirement has efficiently drove you away from the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This thing I'd normally say was pretty cool.

http://www.pismotechnic.com/pfm/

But I've recently accidently copied a sub-repository in a mercurial repository to another folder and when that happened a lot of files got magically messed up. If you don't mind possible issues like that (eg. keeping backups) this could be a solution for you.

I've stumbled upon this question while hunting for an alternative because corrupted files are definitely not on my requirement list.

Comment: I take that back! I should have posted this after I sent a request to their support, not only did they respond in about 1 minute but they also told me how to recover all my data! I'm not going to stop using this tool any time soon now!